# NullPointerException in Android Library Code

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

My Android app has a NullPointerException but there is no code from my app in the stacktrace.  I've gone through the Android source but I cannot figure out where in my code the error is happening.  I do know that there is a problem in the library with the queue but that is a library problem and is not related to my code.  Any help is appreciated.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at cy.run(SourceFile:506)   
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: @hgoebl, yes we are.  but, code usually shows up in plaintext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go the directory %PROJECT_HOME%/proguard_logs and search for "cy" in mappings.txt.
You'll find the real class name (I'd suppose its a Runnable or a Thread). Line number 506 will show you the source of the NPE.

There are better ways to do, so I suggest you spend some time on http://proguard.sourceforge.net/